# Use volumes in docker-compose.yml file for code syncing but can't work properly

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = require('./routes')

const app = express()

app.use(router)

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Server is up on port 3000')
})
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const todos = require('./_data')

const router = new express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Todo APP!!!')
})

router.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
 res.send(todos)
})

module.exports = router
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json . 
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
  version: '3'
  services:
   node_backend_api:
    build: .
    ports: 
     - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
     - "/app/node_modules"
     - ".:/app"
    environment:
     - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Use volumes in docker-compose.yml file for source code syncing. When I change source code from my local project it will also change inside docker container. It works fine when I hit command "docker-compose up" but it can not reflect changes in web browser when I want to see the output.

Comment: It seems like you've attached two PNG files to your question instead of the actual application code.  Can you edit the question to fix this?  Docker usually runs off of fixed images, and once you `docker build` an image you wouldn't typically change the source code in the container; what is your actual work flow here?

Comment: Sir, See the docker-compose.yml file i use volumes for persistent changes. When I hit the command "docker-compose up" it will works fine without any error but when I change source code in my local directory it will also change in container but when i see the output in the browser it will show the old output.

Comment: I will use bind mounts for syncing source code. Source code is also change in docker container but can't update in the browser.

Comment: I will also check the downgrade version of Docker Desktop For Windows but didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

So first, remove : `COPY . .` from your **dockerfile**. You don't want to copy the files from host to container, you want to use volumes.

Then, remove `- "/app/node_modules"` from your **docker-compose.yml** file There is no point in doing this (btw why are you even doing this? please read the documentation : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

Finally re-up your stack while building it :

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Sir, I have tried your solution it can't work :)